# In Jetbrains Rider Datagrip, exporting database with pg_dump throws a search_path error

Tags: postgresql, rider, datagrip, cockroachdb

I have a CockroachDB cluster that i have connected to through JetBrains Rider. I want to make sure I can export all the data (as a backup, for example) using `pg_dump`. However, when running the `export with pg_dump` command from the context menu in Rider, I get the following exception:

```
pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR:  set_config(): invalid value for parameter "search_path": ""
pg_dump: error: query was: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

And as a result, nothing is saved to my target file. Here is a screenshot of the export window and values I am using:
[image: screenshot of export window with values]

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I cannot seem to find related problems like this one.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this expected to work?  I'm surprised not that it is broken, but rather that JetBrains would offer it as an option.

Comment: Here is the official documentation for it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Export_data.html#create-a-full-data-dump-for-mysql-and-postgresql
So I believe it is supposed to work. It just breaks because of the above error.

Comment: The statement SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
works correctly in Cockroach 19 and Cockroach 21.2

Perhaps there are some problems in the settings of its cluster (for some reason, you cannot set such a value for search_path in the config)

Comment: I was just wondering if you attempted to run pgdump command with the same parameters from the CLI and see if this runs without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

[`pg_dump` is not supported for CockroachDB](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/20296) even if runs in cluster